# SQL Syntax error for this situation

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

im programming in Visual basic and I've run across a problem. I've never had to use a between statement before and cannot find out exactly how to do it using the method I am using so that its the same as everything else in my program.

The exact error is :

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ServDate BETWEEN ? AND ? WHERE Description = ?'.
```

Thanks in advance.

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Services WHERE ServDate BETWEEN ? AND ? WHERE Description = ?", Con)

Prm = New OleDbParameter("ServDate", StartDate)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Prm)

Prm = New OleDbParameter("ServDate", EndDate)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Prm)

Prm = New OleDbParameter("Description", "Automatic Oil Delivery")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Prm)
```

Comment: make sure `StartDate` and `EndDate` are actual date variables, then, I thinkt he correct syntax is: `SELECT * FROM Services WHERE (ServDate BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND Description = ?`  (you have 2 `WHERE`s).  Also, OleDB param are positional so be sure to create/add them in SQL order.

Comment: Ah I see, I actually had to do something similar like this earlier in my program (using brackets I mean) and I never realized I could also apply it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be one `WHERE` clause for one `FROM` clause :

```
SELECT * FROM Services WHERE (ServDate BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND Description = ?
```